# Book where interdimensional shape changers invade Earth and the protagonists travel on a cobbled together train to fight them

Tags: story-identification, books

It's about these shape shifting creatures invading Earth, and a team building a cobbled together train to go and find a way of eliminating them. I remember the train had a holly wreath on its front. I must have read it 20 odd years ago.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice overall description of the story but can you remember anything else? Do they find a way of eliminating them? Can you remember who was in the team? How many, what they looked like? Why did they use a train and not something else? Why did they have to make one? If you remember anything else about this or want to alter anything you currently have please [edit] your question to do so!

Comment: Are they using the train to go somewhere else on earth or it allows them to travel to the aliens home dimension?